# Nodejs Docker Development microservices

Tags: docker

I'm building a application with microservices architecture.

So basically, my app look like this

```
API GATEWAY(port 3000) => USERS-SERVICE(port 9090), AUTH-SERVICE(port 8080), SEND-SMS-SERVICE(port 7070).
```

all work fine until now.

now I try to implement docker in my project. I build an image for each service
and run container instance for each on my local machine.

now I want to develop new service Customer-Service. and this service run on

> http://localhost:3030

.

question:

1) How i can request http://localhost:3030 from api gateway, if in development I run api-gateway from container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand the network concept, when you start independent docker instance and you don't define the network they will be unreachable between them.

There is other things, you CAN'T access to one micro service hosted in a Docker to other Micro services hosted in other docker image using `localhost`, `localhost` is a `127.0.0.1`. This is a call for the local machine. Then the concept of docker is like "diferent machines running on a same machine" is like a virtual machine but docker shares the host machine kernel.

You can access to another docker image in 2 ways.

- Configure in a host network, which i do not recommend
- Create a network, add every docker image instance to this network and call other micro services using the container name. IE you can use `http://my-service-1:3400/api/v1/post`

I recommend you to use docker-compose.

This is one of my repositories, I created with the propuse of share an Node App using JWT, but this project use Docker and docker-compose

https://github.com/camiloperezv/jwt-template

how you can see, i define an `Network` attribute in the `docker-compose.yml`and use this network in all of my services.

In the service section you will put all your micro-services, and in the code you will make the http request using the container name instead of using localhost or an IP address.

In my services y use the `build: .` this is for development propuse, in production you should use the pre build docker image instead of building it on the production server.

Feel free to use my github code.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the question, a new service `Costumer-Service` runs on `http://localhost:3030` on the host machine.

If yes, `api-gateway` docker container should be started in the host network:

```
docker run --network host -d <api-gateway_image_name>
```

After this `Costumer-Service` will be reachable on `localhost:3030` from the `api-gateway` container.